# Spring Security - Custom handler for Authentication Failed: Bad credentials

Tags: java, json, spring-security

I have implemented these custom handler in my spring security app

- *AuthenticationSuccessHandler* (`SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`)
- *AuthenticationFailureHandler* (`SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`)
- *AuthenticationEntryPoint*

so I can get JSON response as per my requirement.

In case of successful login I am getting valid JSON response as it is going through my custom *AuthenticationSuccessHandler* but in case of invalid credential it is giving me a *HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: Bad credentials* along with it's default HTML error page.

I want a JSON error response for this instead of default HTML page.
Is there any other handler which I need to implement? If it there then how to configure it in config method?

Here is my Spring Security config method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/list").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
            .antMatchers("/delete-user-*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/edit-user-*").access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .usernameParameter("ssoId")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
            .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
            .tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(86400)
            .and()
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}
```

Here is my *CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler*

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
        jsonResponse.put("error", true);
        jsonResponse.put("message", "Invalid credentials");
        response.getWriter().append(jsonResponse.toString());

        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple things but nothing is working for me till now.

Comment: Are you using JWT based authentication?

Comment: Did you add a breakpoint in your custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler `. Is it executed? And why do you call `super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);`?